# return status code and get message on client side or send error message directly to client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm responding to an AJAX request, but there is a app error. (data validation failed, for example). How to notice the user?

**1. Return Status Code, then get message by JS**

```
$.ajax(options).done(function(response){
    if (response.status === 1){
        // no problem, do next action
    } else {
        alert (messages[response.status]);
    }
});

var messages = {
    '0': 'Server Error',
    '-1': 'Invalid Data',
    ...
}
```

**2. Return Status Code, and a message:**

```
$.ajax(options).done(function(response){
    if (response.status === 1){
        // no problem, do next action
    } else {
        alert (response.message);
    }
});
```

Which one is better? or, what's the best practice? Note that, we have a bilingual application.

Personally, I think first is better. Because I have to at least define an error message in my JS file, for server error. (when AJAX request fails, jQuery `.fail()`) So if I have to do it once, it's better to collect all messages together in same place.

Comment: If you go with option 1, give the user some way to also get access to the underlying message.

Comment: @Kolban: I cant get what you do mean. Could you please explain a little more?

Comment: In your first solution, you are "masking" the underlying message returned from the ajax call by providing your own messages.  This is great and provides a non-technical context on the issue.  However, you are also losing "knowledge" that may be available in the underlying response message (whatever it says).  Ideally, you provide both styles of message.  The first and primary is a clear user consumable message but in addition, I would also try and provide a way the user can "get at" the underlying message if and when needed.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I have always been taught and practiced the second one. Client side validation is nice but it is not reliable because the client can also edit it and cause havoc if they are malicious enough.

It is best to do server side validation and return the messages from there. This gives you and the back end complete control that users can't muck up. The main error that you should have in your ajax calls is some kind of "Internal Server Error" in the error callback function. If the user gets this, then the call would fail anyways because it can't read the server. Any message besides this would mean that the server was successfully reached and performed its internal validation on all passed in data which is where these messages come from.

If you really wanted, you could do validation twice. Make nice jquery validation that doesn't let the call happen if the inputs are completely wrong format. But if it does get to the server, you should go under the impression that you can't trust any input passed in until it is explicitly validated there.

Hope this is informative. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, but data validation was an example. I mean any app related error or message.

Comment: The practice still stands. If you need a true message based on something being received from a server via ajax call, it is much more reliable that the server is giving you the correct response message than your javascript or jquery.